# Dump large SQL table as .csv and split it into multiple separate CSVs for Redshift

Tags: oracle, amazon-redshift

I have a table, let's called it `tableA`, in an Oracle database that I need to upload to redshift. Looked up several methods online, most suggest using datagrip or some other IDE to dump it. The size of the table as reported by Oracle is 89GB so I cannot use DataGrip to dump it as a .csv file. How do I dump it as partitioned .csv so I can use the `COPY` command by RedShift for faster uploads? Please ask for any further info that might be required.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this utility.[util](https://github.com/dmitrydemin1973/powershell-oracle/blob/master/run_export_dir_tables.ps1)
It executes the sql files sequentially and stores the result in separate csv files.
It uses sqlplus in console mode, sqlplus is the best performance utility, but it is not a friendly user.

Try to split the sql by primary key. Set ranges by primary key in separate sql files.
for example

```
sql1.sql
select col1, col2, col3. col4 from tableA where col1 >0 and col1<=1000000;
sql2.sql
select col1, col2, col3. col4 from tableA where col1 >1000000 and col1<=2000000;
sql3.sql
select col1, col2, col3. col4 from tableA where col1 >2000000 and col1<=3000000;
```